# Does an app built with Architecture Components make it "MVVM" and if yes, which parts of the app relate to which layer of MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I couldn't find any source that answers this question directly:

Are Android Architecture Components made to follow an MVVM architecture (if implemented properly)? And if yes, which part of the app (Activity/Fragment, ViewModel, repository, database, web service) relates to "Model" "View" and "ViewModel"? 
The ViewModel class obviously belongs to the ViewModel layer, but what about the rest?

Comment: `Activity` / `Fragment` is a view, `ViewModel` is viewmodel

Comment: And the model? Is it everything from the repository to the different data sources, like room and web services?

Comment: see https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity or Fragment is your VIEW,particular activity/fragment viewmodel represents VIEWMODEL which contains all the business logic of your UI and Model/Repository represents MODEL which contains all the data related logics. You can manipulate data in model and can use Database,web services and Shared Preferences in the Model.